# Detect safari popup blocking setting programmatically in iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, mobile-safari

Is there a way my iphone app can know whether the safari popup blocking setting is enabled or not? or is there a way to prompt user to enable popup for iphone safari browser?